# std::string.find_first_not_of, unexpected return value

Tags: c++, string, find

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%u\n", std::string("\n").find_first_not_of(" \t\n\v\f\r", 0, 1));
}
```

The following program prints 0, not std::string::npos as I expected. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your call matches:

```
size_t find_first_not_of ( const char* s, size_t pos, size_t n ) const;
```

`n` is the number of chars in **s**, and you're passing 1. So, you're searching for the first char that is not space. The rest of your `" \t\n\v\f\r"` string is ignored.

Likely you simply want:

```
find_first_not_of(" \t\n\v\f\r")
```

Answer (score 1):

The third parameter doesn't mean what you think it does.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_not_of/), `string::find_first_not_of` searches for the first character in the object which is not part of either str, s or c, and returns its position. Since "\t" is such character, return value is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you want to print, I can say the third parameter should be the length of string you passed. So here is the corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

int main(void)
{
    std::string s=" \t\n\v\f\r";
    printf("%u\n", std::string("\n").find_first_not_of(s.c_str(), 0, s.length()));

   //since now I'm using std::string, you can simply write:
   printf("%u\n", std::string("\n").find_first_not_of(s));
}
```

Demo at ideone : http://ideone.com/y5qCX

Comment: @James : But I was passing `char*`

Comment: The `char*` is null-terminated; the `find_first_not_of` can determine the number of characters without explicitly passing `s.length()`.

Comment: @James: Yeah. You're right, but I was demonstrating the meaning of third argument!

Answer (score 0):

See it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

int main(void)
{
        std::string s("\n");
        if( s.find_first_not_of(" \t\n\v\f\r", 0, 1) != std::string::npos )
                    printf("%u\n", s.find_first_not_of(" \t\n\v\f\r", 0, 1));
        else
                puts("npos");
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `find_first_not_of` interpret the last argument as the number of char to consider in its first argument, not in the string.

```
size_type std::string::find_first_not_of(
    const char* str, size_type index, size_type num) const;
```

The argument `num` is the number to consider in `str`, not in `this` ! So in your case, it only consider the first caracter of `" \t\n\v\f\r"`. You code is equivalent to:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%u\n", std::string("\n").find_first_not_of(" ", 0));
}
```

If you want to only match a substring of the `std::string`, I think you must call `find_first_not_of` on an explicit substring, that is:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%u\n", std::string("\n").substr(0, 1).find_first_not_of(" \t\n\v\f\r"));
}
```

BTW, [here](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of) is the description of the behavior of the `find_first_not_of` method:

> The find_first_not_of() function either:
>
> - returns the index of the first character within the current string that does not match any character in str, beginning the search at index, string::npos if nothing is found,
> - searches the current string, beginning at index, for any character that does not match the first num characters in str, returning the index in the current string of the first character found that meets this criteria, otherwise returning string::npos,
> - or returns the index of the first occurrence of a character that does not match ch in the current string, starting the search at index, string::npos if nothing is found.

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>` is a bad habit. Use `#include <cstdio>`

Comment: Oh, yes I know, I just copied the code from OP, and updated it to explain what was incorrect. I didn't try to correct every coding style error. I'll change it.